# Inserting copyright symbol in label item in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, legend, license

I have a label item in a print composer map layout. In there I'd like to insert a copyright symbol (red cross). Is there a shortcut or workaround?

[image]

Comment: Copy & paste it from somewhere else.

Comment: You can copy it from here: © - be sure however you have the right to use this symbol ;-)

Comment: or switch to html and use `&copy;`

Comment: Or insert  `[%char(169)%]` (without html)

Comment: or use the on screen keyboard